# Enabling noise suppresion and other effects in Android

Tags: android, plivo

I am using Plivo SDK in a app (https://www.plivo.com/docs/sdk/android/) to make VoIP outgoing call. The receiving end, i.e. the person I'm calling,  hears me with noise and with very bad quality.

According to Android documentation I can use the AutomaticGainControl, NoiseSuppressor and AcousticEchoCanceler within my app if suppported but my phone, which they are. the problem is that Plivo library opens the channel internally, I don't have a way to know the sessionId of the audio.

So, in my app, I just call Plivo classes and request to make an outgoing call:

Outgoing outgoing = endpoint.createOutgoingCall();
  outgoing.call(number);

From there on, Plivo SDK controls everythind, bliding me from how it is making the call, so, I don't know the sessionID or how to apply the noise reduction filters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plivo tech support said thy are working on the framework and it's still in beta state, so I resorted to native Sip functionality which Android provides and frankly, it gives tons of more possibilities. For the time being, I recommend using it instead of Plivo SDK, if your target audience supports it.

Comment: were you able to call once? I am using plivooutbound sample project but nothing happens when i press on call button. I have fill in the username, password and phone number in the sample code.

Comment: Yes, I was able to call. My problem was with the quality of the audio. Check you have correct permissions in your manifest and that the phone has conectivity. Also, set breakpoints and chek if the endpoint is being created. PLivo SDK swallows the exceptions and you won't know. Sometimes the app just closes. That's why I resorted to using native SIP functionality on Android and it's much better.

Comment: Also check your ISP does not block Plivo and Plivo is allowed from your country.

Comment: Thanks, i got it solved with the help of CS team from plivo. I was calling some of my UI stuff plivo callbacks which was crashing the app. I used a separate handler to handle all of that stuff and it working now. Didnt face any issue with quality of audio, it was good for me.